# I have a weird issue in wordpress 5.0 new block editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am facing a weird problem in wordpress 5.0 block editor in which when I want to update any page (means enter any single word in the editor) my whole page design in front end destroys.

I am looking around this problem from last 10 hours now and visited different forums but did not get any help

For better understanding I want you to see this page.

http://tailormadebodiez.net/vip-online-coaching/

I have made a clone of this page in wordpress and just added some space in editor and now this page looks like this

http://tailormadebodiez.net/vip-online-coaching-2/

Everything gone! style, images etc. (only in content area)

This is the picture of backend.

https://prnt.sc/ocesd1  (this is the correct page screen shot)

https://prnt.sc/ocetbm  (this is the clone page screen shot which is same but its front end is not same like the above one)

Backend page screen short (from below) for both pages correct one and cloned one: https://prnt.sc/oceumi

Comment: Is there any error logged in the console? Check with inspect element on the error page.

Comment: Hi Abhi, there is no error log, number of errors in console are same on both pages and not any error which I can think of as a suspect

Comment: Can you resolve the `slick` is not a function error caused on the cloned page which is probably because of a check that is only loading the js on home page. In order to quickly verify if the error is due to a conditional check, go to **Settings>>Reading** and make your cloned page as home and see if the page works fine.

Comment: Hi Faham, I did that but nothing changed, moreover my homepage also disturbed now

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing classic editor plugin to get theold look of your website. You can download from the below mentioned link

https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/